# ¿Cómo realizarian esta funcion en php?

Tags: php

Necesito que una variable aumente en 1 por cada click pero que este no se haga 0 de nuevo despues del click

```
$factura = 0;
if(isset($_POST['comprar'])){

echo '<script>window.location="../checkout3.php";</script>';

$nombre = $_SESSION['nombre'];
$apellido = $_SESSION['apellido'];
$direccion = $_SESSION['direccion'];
$provincia = $_SESSION['provincia'];
$ciudad =  $_SESSION['ciudad'];
$zip = $_SESSION['zip'];
$fono = $_SESSION['fono'];
$email =$_SESSION['email'];
//necesito que factura se aumente 1 por cada click en comprar
$factura +=1;

$resultado=mysqli_query($conect,"INSERT INTO Clientes 
(Nombre,Apellido,Direccion,Provincia,Ciudad,Zip,Fono,Email) VALUES 

('$nombre','$apellido','$direccion','$provincia','$ciudad',
 '$zip','$fono', '$email')");
$resultado2=mysqli_query($conect,"INSERT INTO Factura 
(factura,Nombre,Subtotal,Envio,Total) VALUES 
('$factura','$nombre','$suma','$envio','$totals')");

}
```

Comment: pero lo estas haciendo 0 en la primer linea!

Comment: claro comienza en 0 peor despues tiene que ir aumentando peor sin que vuelva a 0

Comment: pero por eso mismo.. la primer linea siempre lo pasa a 0!

Comment: y como lo dejarias $factura +=1 sin nad a mas proque  ya le borre el que dice =0 y me sigue dando 1 siempre que doy click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todo esta bien en tu codigo, puedes tratar esto

```
$factura = 0;
$factura = $factura++;
```

esto es en php pero también puedes hacer un auto incremento de esa variable en la configuración de la  base de datos

Comment: si ya lo hice gracias de todos modos no em di cuenta de la burrada que hice